# How to change "scopes" with Auth2.0 (Connexion, Swagger)

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, swagger, access-token, connexion

I am tying to understand this authentication-example with OAuth2.0 and am stuck at the scopes part: https://github.com/zalando/connexion/tree/master/examples/swagger2/oauth2

In app.yaml, we define 'uid' to be the necessary scope for our application:

```
  /secret:
    get:
      summary: Return secret string
      operationId: app.get_secret
      responses:
        200:
          description: secret response
          schema:
            type: string
      security:
        # enable authentication and require the "uid" scope for this endpoint
        - oauth2: ['uid']
```

In the security-definitions of app.yaml, the "uid" is again in the scopes section and is required as an answer from the x-tokenInfoUrl (which I need).

```
securityDefinitions:
  oauth2:
    type: oauth2
    flow: implicit
    authorizationUrl: https://example.com/oauth2/dialog
    x-tokenInfoUrl: http://localhost:7979/tokeninfo
    scopes:
      uid: Unique identifier of the user accessing the service.
```

In our mock application for tokeninfo (mock_tokeninfo.yaml), we see that "uid" is returned and that the scope is actually "uid", which we wanted.

```
return {'uid': uid, 'scope': ['uid']}
```

And finally in mock_tokeninfo.yaml, we have the "uid" and the scope in the response:

```
      responses:
        200:
          description: Token info object
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              uid:
                type: string
              scope:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
```

So what I understand now is that when app.py starts on port 8080 and I call localhost on port 8080 with "/secret", the security-part checks what is required and sees "uid". It follows the x-tokenInfoUrl on localhost:7979, where we started our mock_tokeninfo application and it returns to us a "uid" and the scope "uid".

Now my question is the following: I have now an own identity provider and would like to access the userinfo from there. I changed the x-tokenInfoUrl to something like this:
`https://<my_idp>/<some_paths>/userinfo`
and when I make curl like this: `curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>‘ https://<IDP>/<some_paths>/userinfo`, it works and I get a response that looks like this:

```
{"mail":"<my_email>",
"name":"<my_name>"}
```

Now as far as I understand, I would only need to change "uid" to e.g. "mail" and it should return my email to me, but no: I get

```
403 - forbidden
provided token does not have the required scope
Content-Type: application/problem+json
```

I don't understand why I don't have the required scope - it simply does not make sense to me. Can somebody please explain, how can I get my information out of my identity provider? I also checked and in my authorization email with my id and secret, it says that scope is <some_keyword>, but this keyword also results in 403 like everything else.

Ps: I've already passed my certificate to the identity provider, so this should not be the problem.

**EDIT**:

Please - help me you intelligent ppl of StackOverflow :(

I found those "MUST naming conventions for scopes": https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/
But it did not help as well.

I checked, if the header is actually redirected and it was.

I found this statement: "However, to make this explicit you should assign the uid pseudo permission in this case. It is the user id and always available as OAuth2 default scope",  but again - if this is a pseudo-permission, how do I do a normal scope?

In every example that I find (the pet-read/write example is the most common one), the scope-variables seem to have custom names... (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/)

Here the documentation for the "security"-section, maybe I misunderstand something: https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html

Comment: Just to clarify: With "My own identity provider" I mean "SIAM - an official identity provider".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution is finally found. The problem is that the documentation was not updated. This is the link to the documentation:

https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#oauth-2-authentication-and-authorization

And it says that:

> The sub property of the Token Info response will be passed in the user argument to the handler function.

Further investigation resulted in finding this commit message of the connexion-package:

https://github.com/mnylen/connexion/commit/1818c34ecbdd6833a6c8cde61021ece38b59d978

Which updates the insufficient description by that phrase:

> The Token Info response will be passed in the `token_info` argument to the handler
> function. The `sub` property of the Token Info response will be passed in the `user`
> argument to the handler function.

So putting the information about "No Scopes" from here:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/

together with the information from the commit-message, we can change our example like following:

```
app.yaml:

security:
    # enable authentication and require the "uid" scope for this endpoint
    - oauth2: []

securityDefinitions:
  oauth2:
    type: oauth2
    x-tokenInfoUrl: https://<my_idp>/<some_paths>/userinfo
    scopes: {}
```

And instead of using "user", we use "token_info" in our function:

```
app.py:

get_secret(token_info):
    return token_info
```

This way, I got all the information that was passed by our identity-provider.

Thank you all for thinking with me :) Hope, you find this useful.